# ng-file-upload using by keeping in node modules

Tags: angularjs, npm, ng-file-upload

I am working with ng-file-upload plugin and works for me. but as per my requirement I should not use the plugin in my code or folder and it should in node modules.

How can I use ng-file-upload plugin by using npm and how to access the module in my code ?

Thanks and help is appreciated.

Comment: `npm install ng-file-upload` will create the node_modules folder in your project folder (assuming it doesn't already exist, and that you run the command from your project folder). You can then include the `ng-file-upload` files from that folder. Additionally, you can install using the `--save` option to add `ng-file-upload` to your project dependencies in package.json.

Comment: Hi James, I have installed in my node modules already. but I don't know how to access the module from node modules to my directive. could you please give me some example. thanks

Comment: You use it the exact same way you would if you had just manually downloaded the files and placed them somewhere in your app directory. First, include the relevant files: `node_modules/PATH_TO_NG_FILE_UPLOAD/ng-file-upload.js`. Next, include the module in your app: `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngFileUpload']);`. Finally, inject the service into your controller: `app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload)`

Comment: I have a require js, I need to access the file upload via require js file. since I have more places to us this.Can you suggest me how to configure the node modules path in require js file to avail the directive globally in application. THanks!!!